# Parse ajax json response

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I can't get the data of a JSON object.

This is my API action:

```
    public string GetVideoInfo(uint videoID)
    {
        ApiVideoInfo videoInfo = new ApiVideoInfo()
        {
            Likes = BitVidDb.GetLikes(videoID),
            Dislikes = BitVidDb.GetDislikes(videoID),
            Views = BitVidDb.GetViews(videoID),
        };

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(videoInfo);
    }
```

If i call the API in the browser it returns:

"{\"Views\":396,\"Likes\":1,\"Dislikes\":0}"

However when i call this ajax function:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/API/Video/GetVideoInfo/25',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        complete: function (data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(json["Views"]);
        },
    });
```

It gives me the following error:

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

I've used JSON.stringify to convert it to a string and it outputs this:

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\"{\\"Views\\":396,\\"Likes\\":1,\\"Dislikes\\":0}\"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Is there some additional step i need to take to get the values?
The request seems to be fine Chrome dev tools gives this as the answer to the api:

JSON    {"Views":396,"Likes":1,"Dislikes":0}

Thanks in advance

Jan

Comment: I've tried to directly return the ApiVideoInfo object aswell which gives a cleaner response:{"views":396,"likes":1,"dislikes":0} but i still cannot parse or read the values.

Comment: I think that you need to pass a string as a parameter into `JSON.parse` method instead of json (since you wrote that `dataType: 'application/json'`)

Comment: You are absolutely right thanks for tipping me off. I just needed to parse the data.responseText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only parse strings and data is an object. To get the json as string i just needed to use data.responseText instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/API/Video/GetVideoInfo/25',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    complete: function (data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        alert(json["Views"]);
    },
});
```